# How do I get access to params in my Rails class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a class, called Tab, that needs access to params so that it can check params[:controller].  Two questions?  (1) Where should I put these two classes, Tab and Tabs?  Should they be in lib?  Or in application_helper.rb?  (2) What's an easy way to get access to params in that class?  Should I just add a params parameter to the constructor of Tabs and pass params in at the call site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Where should I put these two classes, Tab and Tabs? Should they be in lib? Or in application_helper.rb?

it can go to lib, ideally we keep all custom classes/modules in lib directory.

2) What's an easy way to get access to params in that class?

I think you are right here, you should add a params parameter to the constructor of class and pass params in it.